# Iteration in Python, i'm confused

Tags: python

```
                         #
                         #

print("n", '\t', "2**n")     #table column headings
print("---", '\t', "-----")

for x in range(13):          #generate values for columns
    print(x, '\t', 2 ** x)
```

I was given this code by my professor and told to modify it with the following instructions.

1. On line 1, define a function that has one parameter n.
2. On line 2, write its body: It returns 2 ** n.
3. Edit line 8 to call your function with x (instead of using the expression
   2** x).
4. The same table will be produced as before.

I did this, but then the table didn't produce the same result as before.

```
def squareIt(n):
    return 2 ** n

print("n", '\t', "2**n")     #table column headings
print("---", '\t', "-----")

for x in range(13):          #generate values for columns
    print(x, '\t', x **2)
```

Please help, as i'm stuck in this chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call your function that you wrote.

```
def squareIt(n):
    return 2 ** n

print("n", '\t', "2**n")     #table column headings
print("---", '\t', "-----")

for x in range(13):          #generate values for columns
    print(x, '\t', squareIt(x))
```

Comment: Thank you, that was accurate.